# Create a list reading a file with SML

Tags: sml, polyml

I'm trying to create a List reading a text file, for example I have a text file like this `"1 5 12 9 2 6"` and I want to create a list like this `[1,5,12,9,2,6]` using **SML**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide this task into several sub-problems:

1. Reading a file into a string can be done with

   ```
   type filepath = string

   (* filepath -> string *)
   fun readFile filePath =
       let val fd = TextIO.openIn filePath
           val s = TextIO.inputAll fd
           val _ = TextIO.closeIn fd
       in s end
   ```

   See [the `TextIO` library](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosmllib/TextIO.html).
2. Converting a string into a list of strings separated by whitespace can be done with

   ```
   (* string -> string list *)
   fun split s =
       String.tokens Char.isSpace s
   ```

   See [the `String.tokens` function](http://sml-family.org/Basis/string.html#SIG:STRING.tokens:VAL).
3. Converting a list of strings into a list of integers can be done with

   ```
   (* 'a option list -> 'a list option *)
   fun sequence (SOME x :: rest) = Option.map (fn xs => x :: xs) (sequence rest)
     | sequence (NONE :: _) = NONE
     | sequence [] = SOME []

   fun convert ss = sequence (List.map Int.fromString ss)
   ```

   Since any one string-to-integer conversion with `Int.fromString` may fail and produce a `NONE`, `List.map Int.fromString` will produce an "int option list" rather than an "int list". This list of "int option" may be converted to an optional "int list", i.e., remove the `SOME` of all the "int option", but if there's a single `NONE`, the entire result is discarded and becomes `NONE`. This gives the final type "int list option" (either `NONE` or `SOME [1,2,...]`).

   See [the `Option.map` function](http://sml-family.org/Basis/option.html#SIG:OPTION.map:VAL) which was useful for this kind of recursion.
4. Combining these,

   ```
   (* filepath -> int list *)
   fun readIntegers filePath =
       convert (split (readFile filePath))
   ```

This approach does yield some potentially unwanted behavior:

- Filesystem errors will make `readIntegers` throw an `Io` exception
- The string `~5` inside the file will be interpreted as negative five
- The string `-5` will produce a failure (`NONE`)
- The string `123a` will produce the number 123 (`Int.toString` is a bit too forgiving)

You may want to address those.